# The File ... is not in a folder shared with the host and cannot be opened by the host

Tags: python, cmd, virtual-machine, host

I want to Open my Python file in a VM with the cmd. When i execute it it always showes these message: The File ... is not in a folder shared with the host and cannot be opened by the host.

How can i fix that?

Comment: Could you please give us some more information as to how the files are organized as well as the command you are executing?

Comment: Yes it is a normal Python file and its a udp Spammer. I want to opent the file in the vm and it should not be on the host only on the vm and there i want to execute it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide many details.  Without a shared folder this can be achieved with `scp` and `ssh` if you have ssh key access fully set up.  Substitute **{mcs["user"]}@{host}.local** with your username and VM name as appropriate.  Substitute **ubuntu.py** with your python file

```
scp ubuntu.py {mcs["user"]}@{host}.local:. 
ssh {mcs["user"]}@{host}.local python3 ubuntu.py
```